# Is there any proposal to uniformize function type qualifiers and simplify abominable function types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20

The [abominable function types](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) combinatory can be a real pain when dealing with template based on function type matching (see [std::is_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function)).

Miscellaneous qualifers including const, volatile, &, &&, noexcept (plus the variadic arguments support) may lead to a large number of template specializations.

However, the `noexcept` specifier allows to use a boolean expression `noexcept(expr)`:

- `noexcept` being equivalent to `noexcept(true)` as default

So, in a future, can we imagine to uniformize all qualifers with this model:

- `const` qualifier will be equivavent to `const(true)`
- `volatile` qualifier will be equivavent to `volatile(true)`
- `&` qualifier will be equivavent to `&(true)`
- `&&` qualifier will be equivavent to `&&(true)`

And, the icing on the cake, make qualifiers deductible to be able to write something like:

```
template <typename Fn>
struct function_traits;

template <typename R, bool CQ, bool VQ, bool LVRQ, bool RVRQ, bool NEQ, ARGS... Args>
struct function_traits<R(Args...) const(CQ) volatile(VQ) &(LVRQ) &&(RVRQ) noexcept(NEQ)>
{
    static constexpr bool is_const_qualified = CQ;
    static constexpr bool is_volatile_qualified = VQ;
    static constexpr bool is_lvalue_ref_qualified = LVRQ;
    ...
};
```

I would like to hear any thoughts about such issues.

Comment: I agree, C++'s syntax is too simple, and a little bit more complexity is exactly what's needed to make it the greatest programming language in the world.

Comment: just to be sure that I understand your motivation. YOu are refering to the implementation of `std::is_function`, right? because that work is already done, you dont have to deal with that complexity anymore, because `std::is_function` is already there

Comment: yes std::is_function is already there, but not std::callable_traits. Do you think implementing your own callable_traits or using a boost like utility solves all the cases implying a template specialization based on function type. Not sure...

Comment: While I like the idea of having it, I don't see that big of a need for it. Plus what Sam said.

Comment: I think you need 48 specializations... That's a lot, yes, but you can generate them with a macro.

Comment: Interestingly, I did float the idea of a proposal like this in the std-proposals google group, but there was not a lot of support. The opposite in fact.

Comment: Also, if meta classes (or some derivative of it) make it into the standard this would likely become obsolete cause future compatibility problems because of the syntax enhancements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a similar suggestion on the std-proposals mailing list previously. See threads [here](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals/2019/09/0469.php) and [here](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals/2019/11/0679.php).

The conclusion from this discussion was that adding such a feature to the language would be a lot of work. Not only would it be necessary to add rules to the language for deducing the boolean arguments to the qualifiers, but there would also be many other issues such as the point at which the qualifiers are instantiated and evaluated. A proposal of this size would also be likely to introduce many other issues that would have to be hammered out.

Gašper Ažman appeared to believe that some form of "computed deduction" would be an alternative solution to the problem that would be more feasible. If you're interested in helping with this effort then I would suggest contacting him.